# How to align elemens inside <ol> with Numbering of <ol> when we have multiple elements inside <ol>

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I need to make like this

[image]

with this mark-up

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2> 
        <h3>consectetuer adipiscing elit</h3></li>
   <li>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        <h3>consectetuer adipiscing elit</h3>
  </li>
   <li>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
        <h3>consectetuer adipiscing elit</h3>
  </li>
</ol>
```

But I'm unable to make H2, h3 inline with Digit

See Jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/ZaV3b/3/

**Questions**

Is my tag selection OK, or are there any better way?

How to get desired positioning?

You can try in my jS fiddle example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
li {font-size:70px;padding-top:40px;}
h2 {font-size:30px;margin-top:-30px; position: absolute}
h3 {font-size:20px;margin-top:0;}
```

Give `h2` an `absolute` position with negative `margin-top`.

See [The Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/mFQrH/).

Comment: Please bring your code from the demo in-line with the answer itself.